# Current value of rotation during a animateWithDuration

Tags: iphone, uiviewanimation

I'm using animateWithDuration to have one of my UIVIew rotating endlessly. Now, I need to get the current value of my UIView's rotation at a specific time. 
I've tried to use the following function :

```
-(float)getCurrentRotation{
CGAffineTransform transform = ((UIImageView*)[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).transform;
return (atan2(transform.b, transform.a));
}
```

but it always returns the same value (M_PI/2) as it's the value I've specified in my initial call to animateWithDuration :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:4 delay:0 options:( UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear) animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    ((UIImageView*)[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0]).transform = transform;
}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                 }];
```

Is there a way to have the current value of the rotation ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using CoreAnimation based animation, your view properties (bounds, transform...) never actually change. What changes are the properties of the layer displayed on screen while animating (see [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/CoreAnimationArchitecture.html)), which is accessible using `view.layer.presentationLayer`.

Thus, the following line will get you the actual transform at the time you ask for it:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CATransform3DGetAffineTransform([(CALayer*)[[[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0] layer] presentationLayer] transform]);
```

You must link against and include the `QuartzCore` framework, which defines `CALayer`, for this to work.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's possible to watch the "value of the rotation" while it is shown on screen. But I'd say it is not, because your view object does have the *new* property value immediately and the animation takes place somewhere deep inside the framework on objects you're not able to reach.

To fulfill your goal I'd separate the rotation into single steps with a granularity sufficient for your needs. Then just count the steps and make the current step available. Could look  a bit like this (not tested, just a scribble):

```
//step and rotator declared as class members
//rotator is the one which is referred to as ((UIImageView*)[self.subviews objectAtIndex:0]) in the original question 
-(CGFloat)currentRotation

{
  return step*(M_PI/16);
}

-(void)turnturnturn
{
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 
                   animations:^
                   {
                     rotator.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/16), rotator.transform);
                     step++;
                   } 
                   completion:^(BOOL finished) 
                   {
                     if(step == 32)
                     {
                        step = 0;
                        rotator.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
                     }
                     [self turnturnturn];
                   }];
}
```